Visual Studio 2022 (v17.12.3) "Create and Assign Field" Ignores Naming Customizations
After updating Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.12.3, I noticed that the "Create and Assign Field" quick action no longer respects the naming conventions I configured in Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Naming.
Previously, I had set up a naming rule for private fields to use an underscore prefix (e.g., _fieldName) as shown in the screenshot below:
Naming Customization Settings
This configuration worked globally for all solutions, and the generated code adhered to my customizations. However, after the update:
The quick action generates fields prefixed with this (e.g., this.fieldName), ignoring my rules.
Here's an example of what I'm experiencing:
Create and Assign Field Behavior
What I Tried:
I added an .editorconfig file (originally generated from an old project)
This resolves the issue, but I have to repeat this process for every new solution, which wasn’t necessary before the update.
Is there a way to make the naming rules global again, so they apply to all solutions without needing an .editorconfig file for each one?
